# Program crashing on a function prototype declaration

Tags: c, crash, memcpy, function-prototypes

I try to practice generic functions writing this function:

`void *scramble(void *arr, int ElemSize, int n, int *indArr);`
But whenever I run the program with a debugger it crashes on the prototype line, using F11 (Step Into) I see the following:

1.

```
#else  /* WPRFLAG */
            __initenv = envp;
            mainret = main(argc, argv, envp);
#endif  /* WPRFLAG */
```

2.

```
if ( !managedapp )
    exit(mainret);
```

And then the console message says that: `The program '[8108] 1.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

This is my program (please ignore logical coding mistakes as I want to solve it on my own):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char BYTE;

void *scramble(void *arr, int ElemSize, int n, int *indArr);

void main()
{
    int indArr[5]={5,4,3,2,1};
    int numbers[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    char letters[5]={'a','b','c','d','e'};

    int *newNum;
    char *newLet;

    newNum = (int*)scramble(numbers, sizeof(int), 5, indArr);
    newLet = (char*)scramble(letters, sizeof(char), 5, indArr);
}

void *scramble(void *arr, int ElemSize, int n, int *indArr)
{
    int i;
    BYTE *read, *write;
    void *res;

    res = malloc(ElemSize*n);

    write = (BYTE*)res;
    read = (BYTE*)arr;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        memcpy(write + indArr[i]*ElemSize, read, ElemSize);
        read += ElemSize;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Posting the code that calls `scramble` would help.

Comment: @chux, I have edited and added the whole code

Comment: Your first call to `memcpy(write + indArr[i]*ElemSize, read, ElemSize)` is `memcpy(write + 5*ElemSize, read, ElemSize);`.  This appears to be outside `write`.  I think you want `int indArr[5]={4,3,2,1,0}`.  (Zero based indexing)

Comment: What debugger are you using? Typically when a program ends with a return code of 0, it completed successfully.

Comment: @chux, that's true, I fixed that already but the program still won't run under the debugger.
\

Comment: @Freddie, Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Suggest posting that fix as in `// [Edit] Your_comment int indArr[5]={5,4,3,2,1};` `int indArr[5]={4,3,2,1,0};`

Comment: @chux, I don't understand, edit it by yourself, I'll approve it and you'll earn the rep. ;-)

Comment: I was still hoping to help solve your "fixed that already but the program still won't run".  It looks good to me.

Comment: Running it in debug mode under VS10 works flawless for you?

Comment: Maybe a `managed` vs. `native` issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37541/discussion-between-chux-and-quaker)

Comment: `main` needs to return `int` you may want to try changing that and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I tried that also :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `memcpy` line:

```
memcpy(write + indArr[i]*ElemSize, read, ElemSize);
```

the destination is not correct for `indArr[0]` if `inAddr[0] = 5`. Think about the memory being a contiguous block, and the pointer `write` points to the beginning. Adding `5 * ElemSize` to write will put it outside the bounds of the memory allocated.

```
 _______________________
|    |    |    |   |    | 1
 -----------------------
^- write                 ^- write + 5 * ElemSize
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, that was a logical mistake and it was fixed already. Even after fixing it the program refuses to run under Visual Studio's debugger.

Comment: The debugger shouldn't even point to that line. Try setting a new breakpoint at the first call to scramble.

Comment: @Freddie Looks like we've been hit by the anonymous down-voter.

Comment: @chux Indeed. You were first to point out where the program would segfault (if the debugger actually ran!), so I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

OP was using 1-based indexing rather than 0-based indexing.  This caused the first memcpy to write outside bounds.  Change code as below.

```
// int indArr[5]={5,4,3,2,1};
int indArr[5]={4,3,2,1,0};
```

---

[Edit]

Further research with @Freddie & I failed to replicate OP's problem.  The 2 steps after the "crash" as posted by the OP are normal steps before a normal exit.  Either something stated is amiss or OP's debugger/compiler just "knew" it need not bother with those pesky `scramble()` function calls and could go home early to Bill's house.